# Angular 2: Understand if DOM element is within viewport

Tags: javascript, angular

Basically I would like to flag a dom element with an @input value, i.e. 'aos'

```
<div aos>my</div>
```

And then for example do a console log whenever such div is within my viewport.

How can this be achieved? I assume using Angular's Scrolling Dispatcher, but how can I understand that such div is in the viewport?

Comment: I have opened a new thread to extend julianobrasil solution to turn this into an 'animate-on-scroll' (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130402/angular-2-animate-on-scroll)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma641298776433166?file=src/app/enter-the-view-port.directive.ts)

You can use an `IntersectionObserver` for doing that. It's a native browser API, not an Angular one. One approach is to build a directive that, when applied to any element will tell you that element is visible/hidden. You can check its [API here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Basically what you have to do in this directive is:

1. Inject the parent of the directive (`ElemenRef`)
2. Observe the parent using an `IntersectionObserver`

```js
@Directive({selector: "[enterTheViewportNotifier]"})
export class EnterTheViewportNotifierDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() visibilityChange = new EventEmitter<'VISIBLE' | 'HIDDEN'>();
  private _observer: IntersectionObserver;

  constructor(@Host() private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const options = {root: null,rootMargin: "0px",threshold: 0.0};
    this._observer = new IntersectionObserver(this._callback, options);
    this._observer.observe(this._elementRef.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {this._observer.disconnect();}

  private _callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => 
        this.visibilityChange.emit(entry.isIntersecting ? 'VISIBLE' : 'HIDDEN'));
  };
}
```

And you can use it like this (`_visibilityChangeHandler` will be called with a message everytime the below `div` enters/leaves the viewport):

```html
<div (visibilityChange)="_visibilityChangeHandler($event)"
     enterTheViewportNotifier>
</div>
```

Final note: it is possible to have an output with the same name of the selector, which could save you one attribute applied to the component, but I'm not sold on that idea yet :)

Comment: Nice answer. One addition though, wouldn't you also need to bind `this` to access `this.visibilityChange` in the callback? `new IntersectionObserver(this._callback.bind(this), options);`.

Comment: @MichaelD, thanks to the arrow functions, there's no need for the binding thing here. We get the context (`this`) at the very moment the callback is created.

Comment: @julianobrasil: I overlooked `_callback` is an arrow function. All good. :)

Comment: amazing! verified and works great in angular15! thank you so much

Comment: it's not removing that element from DOM. it's just make it hidden. Can we completely remove DOM and load it later.

Comment: @pathe.kiran the directive is not intended to add/remove anything from the DOM. It'll notify when the element is in the viewport and that's all.

Comment: BTW, if you want to remove something from the DOM, you can use a `*ngIf`