# Angular 2: Animate on Scroll

Tags: javascript, angular

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6433166/julianobrasil) has provided a nice solution [(STACKBLITZ)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma641298776433166?file=src/app/enter-the-view-port.directive.ts) on how to detect an element within the viewport in Angular. [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129620/angular-10-understand-if-dom-element-is-within-viewport)

I would like to now adjust it, by adding a class to the element whenever it's in the viewport.

This would provide me with a simple Animate on Scroll functionality in Angular, without the need for external libs.

I can't get it to fully work yet though:

CSS Animation to add:

```css
/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */
.slide-top {
    -webkit-animation: slide-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
            animation: slide-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
            transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
@keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
            transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
```

HTML to add the css to:

```html
<div (visibilityChange)="_visibilityChangeHandler($event)" enterTheViewportNotifier>My div to rotate</div>
```

TS:

```js
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

public _visibilityChangeHandler (nativeElement: any) {
    if (nativeElement) {
       this.renderer.addClass(nativeElement, 'slide-top');
    }
 }}
```

And the adjusted viewport class - I just changed the EventEmitter and would return this._elementRef.nativeElement, to which I would then add the css class.

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Host, OnDestroy, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[enterTheViewportNotifier]"
})
export class EnterTheViewportNotifierDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() visibilityChange: EventEmitter<ElementRef> = new EventEmitter<ElementRef>();

  private _observer: IntersectionObserver;

  constructor(@Host() private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 0.0
    };

    this._observer = new IntersectionObserver(this._callback, options);

    this._observer.observe(this._elementRef.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._observer.disconnect();
  }

  private _callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      console.log(entry.isIntersecting ? 'I am visible' : 'I am not visible');
      this.visibilityChange.emit(entry.isIntersecting ? this._elementRef.nativeElement : null)
    });
  };
}
```

It seems to work - but the animation will only play once. Any ideas how I can replay the animation whenever I rescroll to the area again? I can't think of howto remove/readd the css class;/ Any ideas?

Comment: You need to removeClass on element is out of viewport

Comment: Are you try Angular Animations?. if you declare a variable and use `<div enterTheViewportNotifier (visibilityChange)="isVisible=$event"..>` isVisible get the values 'HIDDEN' and 'VISIBLE'