# Custom directive that renders the template when an element is in view

Tags: angular

Is there any Angular directive that functions like a ngIf statement but loads the template when in view? Is this even possible?

I have a large page and would like to take some weight off the dom by rendering the template views when the element is visible. I know there are techniques like virtual scrolling, but is this possible through a directive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I searched kind of this action months ago for rendering images only in view, as far as I reach, the most useful thing is IntersectionObserver. You should think of implementing a directive using this browser API. Further look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Not really related to the OP but to build on the comment by Fatih, for images you can use the loading attribute; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img#attr-loading, if you set it to lazy the browser will take care of loading the image only when it's a certain distance from the viewport.

Comment: Sounds like a nice challenge. I think it’s very well doable using a structural directive combined with an intersection observer..

Comment: yes, using the IntersectionObserver was the route to go. I've posted a solution that uses an EventEmitter to return a boolean value when the element is in view.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a directive that might solve problem.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[isVisible]'
})
export class IsVisibleDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  
  @Output() visibilityChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  private _observer: IntersectionObserver;

  constructor(
    @Inject(ElementRef) @Host() private _elementRef: ElementRef
    ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const options:IntersectionObserverInit = { 
      root: null, 
      rootMargin: "0px", 
      threshold: 0.0 
    };

    this._observer = new IntersectionObserver(this._callback, options);
    this._observer.observe(this._elementRef.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { this._observer.disconnect(); }

  private _callback = (entries: any, observer: any) => {
    entries.forEach((entry: any) =>{      
      this.visibilityChange.emit(entry.isIntersecting)
    });
  };
}
```

[Angular 2: Understand if DOM element is within viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129620/angular-2-understand-if-dom-element-is-within-viewport)